# Playing a Sound While App Runs

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, avfoundation

EDITED 
still not sure whats wrong please help

hi there I'm creating and iOS application and trying to make it play a sound when running I've type up my code in the app delegate .h , .m and it plays the sound fine but the thing is it goes to a black screen when my ViewController.xib has a blue background heres heres the code i have

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
@class ViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    ViewController *viewController;
    AVAudioPlayer *_backgroundMusicPlayer;
    BOOL _backgroundMusicPlaying;
    BOOL _backgroundMusicInterrupted;
    UInt32 _otherMusicIsPlaying;
}


@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet ViewController *viewController;

- (void)tryPlayMusic;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize viewController = _viewController;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    

    // Set up the audio session
    // See handy chart on pg. 55 of the Audio Session Programming Guide for what the categories mean
    // Not absolutely required in this example, but good to get into the habit of doing
    // See pg. 11 of Audio Session Programming Guide for "Why a Default Session Usually Isn't What You Want"
    NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:&setCategoryError];

    // Create audio player with background music
    NSString *ticktockPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ticktock" ofType:@"wav"];
    NSURL *ticktockURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:ticktockPath];
    NSError *error;
    _backgroundMusicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:ticktockURL error:&error];
    [_backgroundMusicPlayer setDelegate:self];  // We need this so we can restart after interruptions
    [_backgroundMusicPlayer setNumberOfLoops:-1];   // Negative number means loop forever

    // Override point for customization after app launch    
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

- (void) audioPlayerBeginInterruption: (AVAudioPlayer *) player {
    _backgroundMusicInterrupted = YES;
    _backgroundMusicPlaying = NO;
}

- (void) audioPlayerEndInterruption: (AVAudioPlayer *) player {
    if (_backgroundMusicInterrupted) {
        [self tryPlayMusic];
        _backgroundMusicInterrupted = NO;
    }
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [self tryPlayMusic];
}

- (void)tryPlayMusic {


    // Play the music if no other music is playing and we aren't playing already
    if (_otherMusicIsPlaying != 1 && !_backgroundMusicPlaying) {
        [_backgroundMusicPlayer prepareToPlay];
        [_backgroundMusicPlayer play];
        _backgroundMusicPlaying = YES;
    }   
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [viewController release];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

ok so thats all the code

[image]

and heres what i get when app loads and the sound works fine

[image]

and this is what i want to get (ViewController.xib)

[image]

Thank in advanced

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    


    NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:&setCategoryError];
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    // Create audio player with background music
    NSString *ticktockPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ticktock" ofType:@"wav"];
    NSURL *ticktockURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:ticktockPath];
    NSError *error;
    _backgroundMusicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:ticktockURL error:&error];
    [_backgroundMusicPlayer setDelegate:self];  // We need this so we can restart after interruptions
    [_backgroundMusicPlayer setNumberOfLoops:-1];   // Negative number means loop forever

    // Override point for customization after app launch    
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

new code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with the sound. Probably a problem with how you are initializing your ViewController. can you post that code? (ViewController.m)

Comment: at the moment i have no code in the view controller.m or .h

Comment: no code at all? just a blank file? There has to be something in it.

Comment: well yeah its just the normal code when you first open a new project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never initialized your view controller.

Somewhere before you do

```
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
```

You need to do

```
self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
```

I see that you declared the property as an IBOutlet.. is it actually hooked up to something in Interface Builder?

---

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:&setCategoryError];
    // Create audio player with background music
    NSString *ticktockPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ticktock" ofType:@"wav"];
    NSURL *ticktockURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:ticktockPath];
    NSError *error;
    _backgroundMusicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:ticktockURL error:&error];
    [_backgroundMusicPlayer setDelegate:self];  // We need this so we can restart after interruptions
    [_backgroundMusicPlayer setNumberOfLoops:-1];   // Negative number means loop forever

    self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Copy that function and just delete this one `- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application` completely.

You should also consider converting your project to use [ARC](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html). It will remove the need to retain/release/autorelease statements.

Comment: where do i had this in app delegate or view controller

Comment: In the `(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application` function.

Comment: The first line is already in your code.. at the end of the function. You need to put the second one somewhere (anywhere) before it.

Comment: ok so i just added and ran my app and nothing happened my friend check my updated code

Comment: I am either missing the issue or it is not visible from what you've posted. Any way you can upload an actual sample project that has this issue so I can run it locally? Should be able to figure it in no time. I have a feeling it has something to do with the xib itself and it is too difficult to figure that out without having it in front of me.

Comment: will i think it might be to do with this I'm going to put it in my answer at the bottom basically its some code in the app delegate and when i run my project it opens up the blue background but does play the sound ^^^^

Comment: You know, I was actually going to suggest changing that around because it's the new standard, but figured it couldn't actually be the problem. So the view works now? Just put all the audio code in that new function and get rid of the old one completely - you don't need it.

Comment: can you edit my answer or copy the code and show me because i will probably delete the wrong code??

Answer (score 0):

You have two targets - are all your resources included in the target that you're building?

Comment: hi there I'm new to Xcode sorry what do you mean by targets ??

Comment: Your project has two targets, probably "playing" and "playing tests". If you select your resources and open the right-side toolbar, and look below the 'Identity and Type' pane - there should be a 'Target membership' pane. The box for 'playing' should be checked